# Table - Hide one element, show another

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm new to JavaScript and I have an issue.

I need to hide checkbox and then show the `span` with the content "canceled".

Can someone help me, please?

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  // Find remove selected table rows
  $(".delete-row").click(function() {
    $('input[name="record"]').each(function() {
      if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
        if (confirm("Are you sure?")) {
          $(this).hide();
          $(this).closest('td').find('.canceled').show();
          console.log("confirmed");
        } else {
          console.log("canceled the deletion");
        }
      }
    });
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<tr>
  <td>First Name</td>
  <td>Last Name</td>
  <td>Address</td>
  <td>
    <input type="checkbox" name="record">
    <span class="canceled" style="visibility: hidden">Canceled</span>
  </td>
</tr>
<br />
<tr>
  <td>First Name 2</td>
  <td>Last Name 2 </td>
  <td>Address 2</td>
  <td>
    <input type="checkbox" name="record">
    <span class="canceled" style="visibility: hidden">Canceled</span>
  </td>
</tr>

<button type="button" class="btn btn-danger marginLeft20 delete-row">Cancel</button>
```

Comment: so what is happening when you run this? Is your alert box even showing?

Comment: paste your table also

Comment: @RyanWilson yes. Alert is showing.

Comment: @whoami code is update.

Answer (score 2):

Based on the code you provided, the alert is showing two times when you cancel for the second checkbox, this is because the first checkbox is hidden but not `unchecked` and the `each` loop condition checks for the checked checkbox. Thus, you can uncheck the checkbox together with hiding it.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  // Find remove selected table rows
  $(".delete-row").click(function() {
    $('input[name="record"]').each(function() {
      if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
        $(this).prop('checked', false);
        if (confirm("Are you sure?")) {
          $(this).hide();
          $(this).siblings('.canceled').css('visibility', 'visible');
          console.log("confirmed");
        } else {
          console.log("canceled the deletion");
        }
      }
    });
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>First Name</td>
    <td>Last Name</td>
    <td>Address</td>
    <td>
      <input type="checkbox" name="record">
      <span class="canceled" style="visibility: hidden">Canceled</span>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <br />
  <tr>
    <td>First Name 2</td>
    <td>Last Name 2 </td>
    <td>Address 2</td>
    <td>
      <input type="checkbox" name="record">
      <span class="canceled" style="visibility: hidden">Canceled</span>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-danger marginLeft20 delete-row">Cancel</button>
```

Comment: @RyanWilson thanks for the correction. Appreciate that

Comment: No problem. Thank you for fixing it. +1 from me.

Comment: You know you could have used JQuery's siblings() function to get the span as well, a little cleaner as you wouldn't have to chain closest() and find(), documentation on .siblings() (https://api.jquery.com/siblings/)

Comment: @Zrna you can create a working jsfiddle and link here

Comment: `.show()` will not work with `style="visibility: hidden"` .. so need to change it to `display:none;` and you can use `$(this).next('.canceled').show();`

Comment: @AnkitAgarwal Of course. Here is it: https://jsfiddle.net/lzrnic/a6c2y83v/

Comment: @Mohamed-Yousef If he sets it to display:none, it won't show either

Comment: @Zrna Here is a working fiddle, using .css('visibility', 'visible') to make the span show. Built off of the answer by Ankit, (https://jsfiddle.net/a6c2y83v/6/)

Comment: @AnkitAgarwal actually it does work now.

but now, when I go to delete second time, alert is showing two times.
someone knows how to solve that?

Comment: @RyanWilson Thanks a lot for helping.
Can you help me now with previous comment?

"but now, when I go to delete second time, alert is showing two times. someone knows how to solve that?"

Comment: @Zrna that's because of the logic you have in your function, you are looping and if the checkbox is checked you call an alert, you should check for checked as well as if the span item is hidden or not before displaying alert.

Comment: @RyanWilson should be fine now

Comment: @AnkitAgarwal Good work sir, still have a +1 from me.

Comment: @AnkitAgarwal Yes! Thank you! You've saved me from losing this little hair I have :)

Answer (score -1):

on checkbox click

```
$(this).hide();
$('span:contains("canceled")').show();
```